# Make Bootstrap navbar opaque

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a navbar fixed at the top. I've customized bootstrap navbar to be completely white in color, but when I scroll down the, the scroll-down screen mixes with the navbar , thereby hindering the contents on the navbar, because the navbar  being transparent. How do I make the navbar fix and opaque so that when I scroll down the content should not collide with the navbar.

Comment: Could you show us what code you have currently, with marking where you've edited it? Please try to make it short.

Comment: Hmm, your navbar is transparent, then use a solid white or semi-transparent white background to the navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in your navbar css : `opacity: 1` and/or `z-index:99` (99 to be on top of other elements, but you can start at 10 for example)